# How to use events of SwipeView in qml?

Tags: qt, events, qml, swipeview

I have created an new project of qt quick controls 2 .It have an `SwipeView` as default.

Now I want to use  `onIndexChanged` event of `SwipeView` but I got an error

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

    Page1 {
    }

    Page {
        Label {
            text: qsTr("Second page")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
    onIndexChanged: {  //error is in this line
        console.log(index)
    }
}
```

**Error**

> qrc:/main.qml:25 Cannot assign to non-existent property "onIndexChanged"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SwipeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html) does not have such property as `index`. You probably meant `currentIndex`.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

SwipeView {
    // ...
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        console.log(currentIndex)
    }
}
```